# When using docker with nodejs and babel, the transpiling process is cached. How to avoid caching?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, babeljs

Given below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/api

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# install PM2 
RUN npm install -g pm2

# copy PM2 config file
COPY ecosystem.config.js ./ecosystem.config.js

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN rm -rf build
# Run the build command to transpiling (This step is skipped)
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8000

# Run for production
CMD [ "pm2", "start", "ecosystem.config.js", "--no-daemon" ]

# Running when using in dev mode
# CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
 api:
 build: .
 ports:
 - 8080:8000
 volumes:
 - .:/usr/api
```

I am using the express-babel framework for development. The image is working fine for nodemon (i.e. in development mode) and skipping the RUN npm run build command cause of caching

Comment: Hey man, just wanted to check if my answer below resolved your problem, and if not, what else I could add to help. Please comment if you have additional questions or upvote and accept if this resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `RUN` instruction will only be executed when the container is built for the first time. Unless something changes in the lines above the RUN instruction, the output is cached and not rerun.

If you want to run build `npm run build` whenever the container is started, it would be best to place it in the `CMD` instruction.

`CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run build && npm run dev"]`

Comment: I have a mounted volume as you can see in the docker-compose file so whenever I am changing anything in my host machine I can see the change inside the container as well but again the build command is not working even after I made this change suggested by you

Comment: You'll have to restart the container for the change to reflect. `docker-compose restart`

Comment: No it's not actually that, the problem is with PM2 because I am unable to find a way to build the project in watch mode for PM2

Comment: Did you try this? http://pm2.abingoal.com/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/

Comment: The problem is I am using express-babel and I want to build it using npm run build before running pm2 on changing my src files. So now when the src files are changing, the container is getting the latest files but the build process is skipped even when I am using this : 

CMD ["sh", "-c", "rm -rf build && npm run build && pm2-docker start ecosystem.config.js" ]

pm2-docker is similar to running pm2 with --no-daemon

Answer (score 0):

so if I understand your problem correctly, you're saying that when running docker-compose up with the image you gave above, with the production commands active and the dev commands commented out, that `RUN npm run build` is skipped?

So I think the problem is with your compose file rather than your Dockerfile. I actually had a similar problem today.

So when Docker is building your image from the Dockerfile, if there is any change to your source code since the last `docker build`, or anything that you passed as your build context for that matter, then the cache will fail and have to rebuild the rest of the lines after `COPY . .`. I think you know that, just wanted to clarify.

*The problem is that docker-compose doesn't know that it has to rebuild your image.*

When you specify the `build: .` line your in docker-compose.yml, docker-compose automatically builds the image from the default Dockerfile, and automatically tags it as `[currentworkingdirectory][service-name]:latest`. The problem is that docker-compose will **only** rebuild the image from your Dockerfile if it doesn't see an image with this tagging scheme. Even if there's a change in your Dockerfile, docker-compose doesn't know it should rebuild, only a change of name will make it rebuild.

So there's a few things you can do to solve your problem.

First, you can just manually run `docker-compose build` whenever your Dockerfile changes or whenever you just want to make sure that docker-compose is using a freshly built image.

Secondly, you can add an additional line to your docker-compose of the form `image: 'docker-hub-username/repo-name:tag'`. You can put this right above the build line with the same level of indention. When you have this line, when docker-compose build your image, it will tag it according to what you have specified in this line. If that line changes at all, it will also trigger a rebuild. So using this option, you would have something like this for your docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    image: 'docker-hub-username/repo-name:tag'
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/api
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need anymore detail or clarification. So long story short, it's docker-compose not build, not docker build using the cache.

Also, I would suggest using different images, one for dev and one for prod, rather than commenting out lines, and also different services for dev and prod in your docker-compose as well. Typically, in a production container, you want to build your source code when building the image. In a dev container, you plug in your source code and have some kind of watcher that rebuilds your code on changes.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know. I doubt if you have read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812414/when-using-docker-with-nodejs-and-babel-the-transpiling-process-is-cached-how?noredirect=1#comment86647502_49813951

Comment: I took that into account when giving my answer. Read over my response thoroughly; it should explain the issue you're having. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Great. I will let you know.